# Error installing and running pywin32 2.7

Tags: python, winapi, installation, pywin32

I am coming up with a couple errors after installing:

> pywin32-217.win32-py2.7

I have recently upgraded ArcGIS to 10.1 and it uses Python 2.7 (as opposed to 2.6 that came with ArcGIS 10.0)

When I run the installer on a Windows 7 64 bit, it installs, but throws the following message:

> close failed in file object destructor:
>
> sys.excepthook is missing
>
> lost sys.stderr

I had a simple python script to print to a printer from a folder containing .pdf files which worked before my upgrade

```
import arcpy, glob, win32api, os

pdfLoc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

try:
    copies = int(arcpy.GetParameter(1))
except:
    copies = 1

for pdfname in glob.glob(os.path.join(pdfLoc, "*.pdf")):
    fullpath = os.path.join(pdfLoc, pdfname)
    for copy in range(copies):
        win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdfname, None, ".", 0)

del fullpath
del pdfname
del pdfLoc
```

Now when I run the script, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "Z:\ESRI\Python\Solstice_Tools_Scripts\Printer_Tools\Batch_Print_From_PDF_Only\BatchprintFromPDFOnly_Test.py",
>   line 34, in 
>       win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdfname, None, ".", 0) error: (31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not
>   functioning.')
>
> Failed to execute (BatchPrintFromPDFOnly2).

I've been googling around and have tried a few solutions, like running the executable in troubleshooting mode, but the error persists. Can anyone suggest what may cause this?

As a side note, I upgraded 4 computers in my company to the new version of python and ArcGIS, and only one of them is throwing this error. The rest work fine.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: If it's only a problem on one computer, is it simple to uninstall/reinstall on that machine?

Comment: @ Thomas. I've tried to uninstall multiple times. Unfortunately, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem, but solved it a bit differently. Instead of creating another admin account, I was able to execute the `pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe` successfully from a command prompt that I started with *Run as Administrator*.

Comment: This worked and it seems to be a much easier solution. Kudos!

Comment: **Same worked for me**.  I also made sure that my path variables `PYTHONPATH=D:\Python27` and `PYTHONPATH=D:\Python27\Scripts` were set properly.

Comment: Run as Admin worked for me as well. I'd be curious to understand why.

Comment: Running the exe as admin didn't work for me. But as he said starting a command prompt as admin and then running the pywin32 from there worked!! Strange! Mine is Windows 8.1, python 2.7.9 64 bit

Comment: This also worked for me, whereas directly running the exe in admin did not (same as atique).

Comment: Same problem as asker and this solves it for `pywin32-220.win32-py2.7`

Answer (score 9):

An alternate solution is what Mark Hammond suggests [on the pywin32 mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-June/012388.html):

> > This seems to happen if User Access Control (UAC) is disabled - is it
> >     disabled for you?
>
> Either way, try running "python scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install"
>   from the root of the install directory and things should finish registering
>   - that should fix the next error you see.

This worked fine for me.

Comment: Run this post-install script worked for me, as the "Run as Administrator" tip had failed. Thx

Answer (score 6):

You must *not* install as administrator, see this [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29300152):

> This is maybe because you are running Windows under the "Administrator" account and anything you normally run is equal to a "run as Administrator"
>
> And paradoxically running the installation of pywin32 on Windows 7 as Administrator causes this error.
>
> So a workaround is to create another admin account
>
> net user Admin /add
> net user Admin 
> net localgroup Administrators Admin /add
>
> and then run the pywin32 installation with
>
> runas /user:Admin pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: worked for me too, just have to setup a password for the account (can be done from computer management).

Comment: Yup! This worked perfectly - just don't forget to set the password or you may get the error: "1327: Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced." Haha, guess how I know this... :-)

Comment: Oh, and this may seem obvious, but remember your pywin file may not be the same so the last line may differ.  For example, mine was: runas /user:Admin pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Comment: That is AMAZING. I actually didn't login as Administrator but still got this error. However, once I use runas with my current account, it works.

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions helped me (Sitting on Windows 10).

But I finally got it fixed when I ran c:\python27\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install

After installation you can try to run the installer again just to be sure, worked for me.

Comment: I got `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found` because of that

Comment: I am using Windows 10  too btw. I didn't get this problem in the previous versions of Windows

Comment: ran c:\python27\scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem as the author. I used the script from [Tim Golden python staff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html#shellexecute) to print a text file. After running, there are errors like the following:

pywintypes.error: (31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')

My system is windows 7, 64 bit. The python is python2.7 64bit.

I think the error has nothing to do with pywin32's installation or windows system settings. I guess the reason is the default opening software setting to .txt file. Because after I changed the default opening software from Nodepad++ to notepad, then I can print the file on my Hp printer.

Comment: Same thing here, if default app is notepad instead of notepad++ Tim's script works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Running from a `PowerShell command as admin` worked for me on Windows 10, where as a `Command line prompt (as admin)` failed.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install pywin32 -

1. net user Admin /add
2. net user Admin
3. net localgroup Administrators Admin /add
4. runas /user:Admin pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when I installed pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe by running the installer file as administrator.

Once I installed it by simply executing the file (double clicking on it), I didn't face this issue again.

I am on Windows 7 64 bit SP1 with Python 2.7.9 (64 bit)

However, I did notice one strange thing, if I just double clicked the installer exe it took slightly over 20 seconds for the prompt to appear whether I would like to run the exe file or not, whereas in case of running the file as administrator, it happened right then (didn't have to wait for that long)
I am using 120 GB SSD so can't question the slowness of Hard disk in this case.

Anyways, here's the output after successful installation of pywin32 in my case:

```
Copied pythoncom27.dll to C:\Windows\system32\pythoncom27.dll
Copied pythoncomloader27.dll to C:\Windows\system32\pythoncomloader27.dll
Copied pywintypes27.dll to C:\Windows\system32\pywintypes27.dll
Registered: Python.Interpreter 
Registered: Python.Dictionary 
Registered: Python 
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Pythonwin has been registered in context menu
Creating directory C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py
Shortcut for Pythonwin created
Shortcut to documentation created
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```