# How do I install web2py in a virtualenv in Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows-7, virtualenv, web2py, pywin32

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to install web2py in a virtualenv. I'm running a 32 bit python 2.7.3 installation on a 64 bit Windows 7.

From what I read, this should be the process:

- install virtualenv (done)
- create the virtualenv (done)
- install pywin32 in that env (I've read it needs to be installed before the web2py installation)
- install web2py in that env

First and foremost: is that right? If so, then...

I tried installing pywin32 through

'''easy_install pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe'''

It went fine. Then, I checked the virtual environment's site-packages for a pywin32 folder and it was there, but I couldn't import it into python ('''ther's no module pywin32'''). The environment was definitely active (I double-checked).

As a test, without using virtualenv, I double-click-installed the pywin32 binary (downloaded the 32 bit version for python 2.7 -- pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe) but got an error at the end:

'''close failed in file object destructor:

sys.excepthook is missing

lost sys.stderr'''

I downloaded the file again (could be corrupted), tried installing it again but got the same result.

Could anybody guide me or point me to a step-by-step install of pywin32 (if necessary) and then web2py for windows 7? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Yes, it was definitely active, I could even see the pywin32 folder in the site-packages in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a bug: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3402824&group_id=78018&atid=551954,
workaround here : http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/rev/a64d8ac23e61
similar to this: [Error installing and running pywin32 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106281/error-installing-and-running-pywin32-2-7)

Comment: I will try the approach described in your links (installing the binaries with a different account - not the Administrator account) to see if I can install it in my 'main' Python installation, but I would still like to be able to install pywin32 (and, later, web2py) in a virtualenv. Could anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the command `easy_install pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe` under an active virtualenv works fine.

To test the installation of pywin32, from python you can try:

```
from win32api import GetVersionEx
print GetVersionEx()
```

Obtaining something similar to (windows major version, minor version, build number, platform id, additional informations):

```
(6, 1, 7601, 2, 'Service Pack 1')
```

You cannot import module `pywin32` because it doesn't exist.

After the installation of pywin32, you can install web2py under the active virtualenv (I tested it until to opening the admin interface, no guarantee after this :-):

- download the source code from http://www.web2py.com/init/default/download
- unzip it to `...\`*`virtualenvdir`*`\Lib\site-packages\` (obtaining: `...\`*`virtualenvdir`*`\Lib\site-packages\web2py\...`)
- cd to `...\`*`virtualenvdir`*`\Lib\site-packages\web2py`
- start the web2py server: `python web2py.py`

At the date, I couldn't install web2py using `pip`. First of all, it grabs an old version of web2py from PyPy. When I tryed to use this version of web2py I got an error `ImportError: No module named ...`. The same using pip on a copy of the web2py source file.