# Python 3.4 :ImportError: no module named win32api

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I am using python 3.4 on windows 7. In order to open a doc file I am using this code:

```
import sys
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("MyDocument")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
```

I'M not sure why is this error popping up every time:

```
ImportError: no module named win32api
```

Although I have installed pywin32 from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)
and I have also checked the path from where I am importing. I have tried reinstalling pywin32 as well but that doesn't remove the error.

Comment: Just to make sure: You installed the version for Python 3.4, and for either win32 or win-amd64, whichever one matches your Python installation, right?

Comment: Also, try `import win32api` directly from an interactive interpreter. And, while we're at it, `import importlib; print(importlib.util.find_spec('win32api')`)

Comment: thnxx @abarnert .... going to try this now.

Comment: @Maxxie which file did you download from that link?

Comment: @Patrick i downloaded - pywin32‑219.win32‑py3.4.exe...its ok i guess coz m using python 3.4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to install pywin32 from here :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

depends on you operation system and the python version that you are using. Normally 32bit version should works on both 32 and 64 bit OS.

EDIT: moved to https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Answer (score 17):

This is a bug in the library itself, probably they used a different python implementation for creating this.

What they are trying to import is the site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd file, but the win32 folder is not in the path that python searches in, but site-packages is.

Try to replace the `import win32api` (inside win32com\__init__.py) to `from win32 import win32api`

Comment: When neither (1) `pip install pypiwin32` nor (2) Nima's answer worked for me (Python 3.7 64 bit on Win 10), I successfully tried yours (3), but after a reboot (4), `import win32api` works too. Don't know whether (3) or (4) did the trick. May be (2) isn't needed either.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same error yestoday with Python 3.6.1 on Windows 7, and resolved it by "pip install pypiwin32".

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error trying to import win32com.client (using Python 2.7, 64-bit).  I agree with [TulkinRB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3143718/tulkinrb), there seem to be path issues, but the fix suggested did not work for me, since I also could not import win32.

Perhaps my fix will also work in Python 3.4.

Eventually, installing the .exe from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) as an administrator (as suggested in [Rina Rivera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3188504/rina-rivera)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106281/error-installing-and-running-pywin32-2-7/21081675#21081675)) allowed me to import win32com.client from IDLE, but *not* when I executed the script I was originally trying to run.

In the end, I discovered 3 differences in the sys.path that had been extended when I installed as admin and opened IDLE, but were not applied when executing a script. By extending the sys.path in my script, I was able to get rid of the import errors when I executed it:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(('C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'))
```

Finally, if you want more than a temporary fix, the sys.path could be permanently extended by establishing IDLESTARTUP or PYTHONSTARTUP variables (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610782/import-a-module-or-add-a-path-one-time-forever-in-python) and [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-python/2009/11/msg00081.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the __init.py file inside the win32 folder and then go inside the win32com folder and change its __init__.py file, where it is import win32api, change to from win32 import win32api

Answer (score 0):

I ended up debugging and copying and pasting the necessary files into the appropriate folders. It's a work-around until the bug is fixed, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1151#issuecomment-360669440

append the 'pypiwin32_system32' path to your system PATH,

in a script this can be done like:

```
import os
sitedir='C:/where_ever/'
os.environ["PATH"]+=(';'+os.path.join(sitedir,"pypiwin32_system32"))
...
```

from powershell

```
$env:PATH="$PATH;C:\where_ever\pywin32_system32";
python.exe ...
```

for help on site dir, see [What is python's site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory)