# Import a module or add a path one time forever in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to work with smartcard readers. So I must import some modules such as `core` from pycard library.

Q1: How I can do it automatically! Now each time I open PythonGUI I must import it again and again!

Q2: How I can add a path to `sys.path` permanently?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not missing the point here: When you say `PythonGUI`, are you talking about the `Python IDLE`?  Or some other GUI?

Comment: @mattingly890 Yes, The same Python IDLE is the point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1:**

From [the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#startup):

> Upon startup with the -s option, IDLE will execute the file referenced by the environment variables IDLESTARTUP or PYTHONSTARTUP. IDLE first checks for IDLESTARTUP; if IDLESTARTUP is present the file referenced is run.

`IDLESTARTUP` is an environment variable that tells the IDLE the location of a python script to execute on startup, as long as the `-s` option is given when you start the `IDLE`.  Thus you need to edit the script pointed to by `IDLESTARTUP` or `PYTHONSTARTUP`, add the `import ...` statement, and use the `-s` flag to start the IDLE.

**Part 2:**

To add to the `sys.path` permanently, you can edit the same file we edited above (the file referred to by `IDLESTARTUP` or `PYTHONSTARTUP`, and do a

```
import sys
sys.path.append("...")
```

**Note on Environment Variables**:

To figure out if you have a `IDLESTARTUP` variable or `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable defined in Windows, you should be able to go to `Control Panel > System and Security > System > advanced > Environment Variables`.*

*(I'm not much of a Windows user, so you might need to seek out `how to change environment variables in Windows` on other questions or Google).