# ImportError: No module named win32api Error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, pip

When trying to import win32api, win32con modules for my code, I have been getting the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Henil\Desktop\LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Automation-master\LinkedInEasyApply.py", line 16, in <module>
>     import win32api, win32con
> ImportError: No module named win32api
> ```

So I ran `pip install pypiwin32` and the installation went through. But when running the code I get the same "No Module Found".

So I tried `pip install -U pypiwin32` and I get the following output:

> ```
> pip install -U pypiwin32
> Requirement already up-to-date: pypiwin32 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
> Requirement already up-to-date: pywin32>=223 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32)
> ```

However, when I run the program I still get "No module found" error. Do I need to change paths somehow?

I am on Windows 10 64 bit machine.

Comment: Print `sys.executable` in the script. It's probably not "c:\python27\python.exe", in which case your script is either running in a different installation of Python or in a virtual environment.

Comment: Seems likely that the pip you are running is for a different installation than you run your python script

Comment: Maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257274/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-win32api/26485933

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i'm importing this modules:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch
win32c = win32.constants
```

I'm using win32 to open Excel files:

```
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlsx_file)        

    wb.Save()
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked