# Not able to install win32api in python

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to run a python code and when I run it I get this error

```
No module named win32api
```

I tried installing it with pip install pywin32 but then I get this error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

How do I install this package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.4 :ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257274/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

Comment: What's your *Python* version?

Answer (score 2):

I tried many solutions and the one works for me :

```
pip install pywinutils
```