# How to install win32api module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, python-module, pypi

*Hi I am writing Desktop notifier code in python but I am getting an error.*

I have already installed the `win10toast` module.

```
import time

from win10toast import ToastNotifier

remTime=input("enter the time")

remMsg=input("enter youor msg")

while True:

    current_Time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    if current_Time==rem_Time:

        print(current_Time)

        break

notify=ToastNotifier()

notify.show_toast("Notification",remMsg)
```

**getting error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\PythonProjects\DesktopNotifier.py", line 3, in 
> from win10toast import ToastNotifier
> File "C:\Users\Ayushi
> Tripathi\AppData\Local\Programs\python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win10toast_*init*_.py",
> line 19, in 
> from win32api import GetModuleHandle ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

**I tried to install win32api then getting another error**

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32api

Comment: `pywin32` depends on you operation system and the python version that you are using. Normally 32bit version should works on both 32 and 64 bit OS. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26485933/11128312). By the way, line 13, use `remTime` instead of `rem_Time`.

Comment: i already have pywin32